# Inspection of variable values in real time debugging

Tags: c, visual-studio

I would like to know if anyone knows how to debug with Visual Studio in real time; I have a firmware for the esp32 microcontroller and wanted to be able to see my variables changing over time without having to use breakpoints. Does anyone know how to do? (If I try to inspect the desired variable, I obtain "optimized-out" instead of the value I'm looking for). Thanks

Comment: It is easier to debug code if you disable optimizations ; use /Od. If you really need to debug optimized code, using /Zo might improve debugging. Visual Studio 2017 and higher also has data breakpoints that trigger when data changes.

Answer (score 0):

It is normal behaviour when you compile with the optimizations enabled. The only way is to disable the optimisations or make the variable `volatile` make sure that it will a permanent storage and it will not be optimized out.